# Why QTableView's selection-background-color doesn't fucntion as expected in Qt4.8.6 via qss?

Tags: qt, background, qtableview, qtstylesheets

My developing qt version is Qt4.7.0 and running qt versin is Qt4.8.6. The OS is identical and that is Ubuntu Kylin 14.04.

There is an weird thing that `tableView->setStyleSheet(QString("QTabelView{selection-background-color:transparent;}"));` works well in Qt4.7.0 but not in Qt4.8.6.

In Qt4.8.6 the default `selection-background-color` is an gray-like color, but when I set `selection-ground-color` to **transparent** the real `selection-background-color` becomes **white** other than **transparent** as shown in the below image. It obviously doesn't work as expected.

[image: The result is beyond expection]

In Qt4.7.0 all is right.

The entire styleSheet is **QString("QTableView{border-image:url(%1); 
padding-left:1px; padding-top:153px; background-color:transparent; `selection-background-color:transparent;`} QTableView::item {border-left: 10px solid transparent;}") 
.arg(g_appPath + QString("/data/image_comm/cabinetV5/5master.png"))**.

**What's wrong with my styleSheet string? Are there other ways to achieve my goal that making `QTableView's` selction cell's background transparent?** Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try another selector like `QTableView::item:selected{ background:.........; }`, which works fine for me.